# Unable to run expo project on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I created an expo project and I am trying to run it on both an iOS and an android simulator. Everything works fine on the android simulator but not on the iOS simulator. I am getting the following error:

```
Error installing or running app. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/Users/.../.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.16.0.tar.app'
```

In advance thanks

Comment: Try the following commands:
1. `killall node`
2. `yarn start`
The metro bundler wasn't able to run on port 8081 for me. But by doing this, it did.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: Maybe there is some dependency that you have not installed correctly. Try the following: 1. `killall node` 2. `yarn` (to install all dependencies) 3. `yarn start`

Comment: I am using npm. I tried the equivalent commands but it still not working.

Comment: Do you have **.watchmanconfig** file?

Comment: No, I only have a babel.config.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons the /Users/.../.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/ install on my computer was version 25 and my project was expo version 26 that is why it could not find the directory. To solve the problem I ran sudo rm -rf ~/.expo to remove the expo on my computer then I just retried it and it worked